# Using gnome-boxes with Remote Desktop Connection

Tags: rdp, gnome-boxes

In the past I used to connect to my Windows server from Ubuntu with remmina (through rdp protocol).
I've recently installed Ubuntu gnome remix (12.10.1) and gnome-boxes and I'm wondering if I can do the same with gnome-boxes.

I've tried creating a new item in gnome-boxes and entering as `url "rdp://x.x.x.x"` as I used to do in remmina bit it says that the rdp protocol is not supported.

Unfortunately, I cannot find any manual or documentation listing the supported protocol or giving instruction on how to connect to a remote desktop.
Can someone help me please?

Comment: I wouls like to know this too. I'm in the same boat...

Comment: +1 Same here, at least I think boxes is supposed to support this...

Answer (score 2):

According to [the todo list](https://github.com/GNOME/gnome-boxes/blob/master/TODO) on github rdp-support is not yet implemented.